# xna the given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

Hello Im working with xna and had a little problem with XACT and playing some background music.Basically I have followed this guide http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/playing-sound to play sound . I have declared all the variables:

```
    private AudioEngine audioEngine;
    private WaveBank waveBank;
    private SoundBank soundBank;
```

and in the LoadContent i have load them their sound information

```
    audioEngine = new AudioEngine("Content\\XactMusic\\inGameMusic.xgs");
    waveBank = new WaveBank(audioEngine, "Content\\XactMusic\\Wave Bank.xwb")  
    soundBank = new SoundBank(audioEngine, "Content\\XactMusic\\Sound Bank.xsb");
```

while at the XACT tool I have created a waveBank and a soundBank and have loaded a .wav file.
The problem is that when I try to compile an error pops up :

Building content threw KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
   What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Try getting rid of the extentions and did you put the music files in the content project?

Comment: Tried that and the same error poped up.Also I have only the inGameMusic.xap file in the Content Folder

Comment: Not exactly sure what is wrong, but the [XNA Content Pipeline Debugger](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/11/01/xna-content-pipeline-debugging-4-0.aspx) might help get more details about the exception being thrown within the content pipeline.

Comment: @AndrewRussell I downloaded the debugger and i think it might have solved the problem.Thank you as well as ClassicThunder for your answers. :)